ASP.NET Core Newtonsoft serialization case
I am using the NewtonSoft json serializer in an ASP.NET Core 8 WebApi.
In my program.cs I have configured like this.
builder.Services.AddControllers()
    .AddJsonOptions(options =>
    {
        options.JsonSerializerOptions.NumberHandling = JsonNumberHandling.AllowReadingFromString;
        options.JsonSerializerOptions.PropertyNamingPolicy = null;
        options.JsonSerializerOptions.PropertyNameCaseInsensitive = true;
    })
    .AddNewtonsoftJson(options =>
    {

    });

I want the serialized properties to retain the case of the model, so if I have
    [HttpPost, Route("api/error")]
    public async Task<dynamic> Error()
    {
        return new { Error = "Bad" };
    }

This serializes as
{ error: "Bad" }

The error has lost the upper case E. How do I stop that?

I just defined ContractResolver on SerializerSettings with NamingStrategy = new DefaultNamingStrategy() as below:
.AddNewtonsoftJson(options =>
{
    options.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver = new DefaultContractResolver
    {
        NamingStrategy = new DefaultNamingStrategy()
    };
});

and it worked :)
